# white screen on ionic both ios and android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, capacitor

I have tried every thing and it's sucked

I have tried every this in google search nothing was work

I'm not sure what is the problem but i got this error while running this command 'cordova run android'

```
Command failed with exit code 1: /Users/aminaibrahim/Desktop/ionic_pro/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/aminaibrahim/Desktop/ionic_pro/platforms/android/build.gradle
```

and this command ionic 'cordova run android --prod' gives me another error with the code but I couldn't change it, like this error "The Component 'LoginPage' is declared by more than one NgModule"

Here is my initializeApp function

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      // Commenting splashScreen Hide, so it won't hide splashScreen before auth check
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.authService.getToken();
    });
  }
```

config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

I really don't now what to with it

here is xcode logs if thats will help

```
2020-11-26 13:13:42.765734+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] Apache Cordova native platform version 6.1.1 is starting.
2020-11-26 13:13:42.766130+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-11-26 13:13:42.871102+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2020-11-26 13:13:42.925675+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:42.926209+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "AutoInjectCordova" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:42.926526+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "AudioCanMix" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:43.059379+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "WKSuspendInBackground" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:43.059841+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.196321+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.196710+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "AllowLinkPreview" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.199612+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.199919+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2020-11-26 13:13:46.200447+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] Using Ionic WKWebView
2020-11-26 13:13:46.201920+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][console] 0.162005ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.202530+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.240922ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.207672+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 4.866004ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.208236+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.162005ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.215468+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 6.856918ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.235326+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 19.553065ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.236065+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "KeyboardResize" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.236288+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2020-11-26 13:13:46.236477+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.237487+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "KeyboardAppearanceDark" is not defined and will default to "FALSE"
2020-11-26 13:13:46.237760+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 2.089024ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.238123+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][inappbrowser] 0.163078ms
2020-11-26 13:13:46.238320+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 36.702037ms
2020-11-26 13:13:47.084315+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process MyApp
2020-11-26 13:13:47.084608+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-11-26 13:13:47.087678+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-11-26 13:13:49.739303+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2020-11-26 13:13:53.227267+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] The preference key "AutoHideSplashScreen" is not defined and will default to "TRUE"
2020-11-26 13:13:53.302114+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1840 ms
2020-11-26 13:14:33.714891+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView::
2020-11-26 13:14:33.715287+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView title: Ionic App
2020-11-26 13:14:33.715499+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView location: ionic://localhost/landing
2020-11-26 13:14:33.715680+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView reload: 0
2020-11-26 13:32:17.248233+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView::
2020-11-26 13:32:17.249577+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView title: Ionic App
2020-11-26 13:32:17.250518+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView location: ionic://localhost/landing
2020-11-26 13:32:17.251447+0300 MyApp[1292:3005054] CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView reload: 0
```

Comment: Any luck with this ? experiencing the same issue

Comment: there was i think it was a modules error, try to remove module one by one or just remove them all and try

Answer (score 0):

> CDVWKWebViewEngine shouldReloadWebView

This is indicating you possibly need the inappbrowser plugin.

For iOS be sure you have inappbrowser added to your cordova project. In terminal change directory to root of your Cordova project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Also be sure deployment target for iOS in config.xml is 11

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="11.0" />
```

> Cordova-ios@6 utilises the scheme feature to address a lot of cross origin issues in the WKWebView, which requires iOS 11.

[Here is the reasoning behind setting this to 11. Above quoted from GitHub repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/981#issuecomment-685696469)